# How can i get both float and string in output?

Tags: java, string, groovy

How can I obtain the output `6214.07500000sec`

I am reading this data from the file and trying to insert in a table. I am getting an error because of string error .

I have tried to parse:

```
float t_f = Float.parseFloat(td)
```

Doesn't help.

Please give a suggestion for getting both string and floating number.

Comment: Sorry ! float t_f = Float.parseFloat(td)

Comment: Store it as a `String`; it can't simultaneously be both.

Comment: If you want to change str to float use `toFloat()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def output = '6214.07500000sec'
Map data = (output=~/(\d+(\.\d+)?)(.*)/).find{true}.with{ m-> 
    return [ value: m[1] as Float, measure: m[3] ] 
}
println data
```

result:

```
[value:6214.075, measure:sec]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't store the full `String` in a `float` since you got the "sec" at the end, one solution could be as @notyou said in the comments to store everything in a `string`, another solution could be to separate the letters from the numbers, here's a short code that will do the trick:

```
String output = "6214.07500000sec";

    String letters;
    float number;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(output);
    number = Float.parseFloat(scan.findInLine("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"));
    letters = scan.next();
    System.out.println(number);
    System.out.println(letters);
```

this code prints:

```
6214.075
sec
```

if you want all the zeros you have to store it as a `String`.

Comment: Thank you so much omega. This is what i was looking for "Scanner"